# Angular - Save Drop Down List State using Local Storage

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, local-storage

When I change the Drop Down List Value and Click the save button the value saves in the local storage as "ng2-webstorage|packagingoptions   ["Yes"] "

When I refresh the page I want the selected value to still be shown as ["Yes"] 
but it keeps going back to the default value even though it is saving correctly to local storage.

All my Text Inputs are saving after I refresh but not the Drop Down Lists.

[Here is an Image of the Problem I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqTE4.png)

Any advice?

Thanks.

```
    //HTML 
    <ngx-select-dropdown [options]="packagingOptions" formControlName="packOpt" 
    [(value)]="dataModel4" [multiple]="false"></ngx-select-dropdown>

   <button (click)="setLocalStorage()">Save Progress</button>

      //Component.ts
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import { AppComponent } from "../../app.component"
import {Ng2Webstorage, LocalStorageService} from 'ngx-webstorage'

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
providers: [AppComponent],
selector: 'app-prod-1',
templateUrl: './product-1.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./product-1.component.scss'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
 export class Product1Component implements OnInit {
   packagingOptions = [
  'Yes', 'No'
  ];
   dataModel4: string;
   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private comp: AppComponent 
   private localSt:LocalStorageService) {
   this.rForm = fb.group({
  'packOpt': [this.localSt.retrieve('PackagingOptions')]
  });
  }
      setLocalStorage(){
      this.localSt.store('PackagingOptions', this.dataModel4);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Are you retrieving the value from local storage when the component loads again?

Comment: What value is `this.dataModel4`, if you do `console.log` what is the value of it? From what I can see it's probably because `["Yes"] != "Yes"`

Comment: When the component loads again the value I selected is still showing in the local storage but I cannot retrieve it.

Comment: I am getting an error when I console.log this.datamodel4. "ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'packOpt' " I see my problem now. Thanks for your help.